# How to Define an Optional Array with a Fixed Size [Swift 3]

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I'm trying to define an array of objects. The array needs to have 3 spaces. At the variable initialization, they're set to nil, but later on in the program, they're filled in (they're filled in before they're used).

Here's what I have so far:

```
var scrollLayers: [SKNode?]! = [nil, nil, nil]
```

And this works fine, but if I have, for example, 50 spots that need to be initialized, I don't want to have to type "nil, " 50 times. Is there a way to make this array 50 spots big and have all those spots set to nil?

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Yet another [documentation fail](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array). "If you need an array that is preinitialized with a fixed number of default values..." It doesn't get any plainer.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the link to the docs! If I'm going to be honest with you, I didn't even know this documentation existed. I'm super new to Swift programming despite, and several google searches, I couldn't figure it out. Thanks again :)

Comment: That documentation is _on your computer_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var scrollLayers = [SKNode?](repeating: nil, count: 50)
```

Comment: any option for non-optional values?

Comment: You can't initialize a non-optional array with optionals, but you can do this: var threeDoubles = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: 3)

Answer (score 1):

For those that prefer this syntax:

```
var scrollLayers: [SKNode?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: 50)
```